# Firebase (android) onDisconnect not being cleared by cancel after tablet reboot

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've been using [**onDisconnect**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect) to remove remove data when a client is disconnected and it has been working well.

When wifi is disconnected for a short period of time, when I reconnect I make sure I [**cancel()**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect.html#cancel()) the previous **onDisconnect** otherwise the 'old' **onDisconnect** triggers using this code.

```
 dbReference.onDisconnect().cancel(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
               databaseReference.onDisconnect().removeValue();
         }
     });
```

My issue is that on device reboot I cannot cancel the old **onDisconnect** that was setup before the device restarted, even though I connect using the same username and password. I'm guessing because the device has rebooted there is a new session/token/something. The documentation states:

> "Cancel any disconnect operations that are queued up at this location"

I would expect to be able to cancel the old **onDisconnect**. Is this a bug? Apart from using a [**ValueEventListener**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) and onDataChanged to monitor for old **onDisconnect** and then reverting the damage. Is there a smarter way to work around this bug?

Note: I'm using firebase 9.8.0.

Comment: WHy do you think you need to?  The tablet was reset.  This means RAM was wiped.  So there's no onDisconnect set anymore, since the dbReference is a local object.

Comment: My understanding is that the onDisconnect is stored on the server - how else does it run when a client goes offline/network issue?